# how to use a constructor from another class with other class constructor in java

Tags: java, constructor

**I'm working with Blue J and I need to use this constructor:**

```java
public BusArrival(int lineNum, int pass, Time1 t)
```

**Time1 - is another class and i need to use the constructor:**

```java
public Time1 (int h, int m, int s)
{
    if (h<0||h>23)
        h=0;
    _hour=h;
    if (m<0||m>59)
        m=0;
    _minute=m;
    if (s<0||s>59)
        s=0;
    _sec=s;
}
```

and i don't know how to connect between them.

Answer (score 0):

you have to extend the class so that you can call the constructor using super() method in the sub class constructor

Answer (score 0):

```
public BusArrival(int lineNum, int pass, Time1 t)
{
lineNum = 0;
pass =0;
t = new Time1(0,0,0);
}
```

This is how you can possibly write a default constructor for BusArrival. Hope this helps.

Comment: great! tnx! when i try to creat a new object i need to add value to the constructor Time 1, how do i add the information?

Comment: Instead of `Time1(0,0,0)` you can call `Time1(10,20,30)` anything you want. Those values will be assigned to object t of Time1 class.

Comment: @user3502175 - hope you got what you wanted.